# R package for combining p-values using Fisher's or Stouffer's method

Tags: r, combining-p-values

Is there an R package (or even a base R function) that implements [Fisher's or Stouffer's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method) for combining p-values? Coding this should be almost trivial, but I'd rather use (and cite) a package.

Example code in this question: [Fisher's method for combing p-values - what about the lower tail?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/59360/6432)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`metap` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metap/index.html) by Michael Dewey implements many methods for combining p-values:

- `sumlog`: Fisher's method
- `sumz`: Looks like Stouffer's method (with weights), this isn't mentioned explicitly in the function's documentation but confirmed in the [draft vignette](http://www.dewey.myzen.co.uk/meta/metap.pdf) (which is not part of the package yet)
- `meanp`: [When combining p-values, why not just averaging?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/78596/6432)
- ...

Comment: The vignette is now in the distributed package.

Answer (score 5):

There's also the `combine.test` function in the [`survcomp` package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/survcomp.html) (on Bioconductor). Implements Fisher's and Stouffer's method, as well as the logit method.

Comment: `survcomp` also works in the edge case of a single pvalue, handles missing values more consistently with base r and encourages contributions by providing an official repo.

Answer (score 2):

There is [poolr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poolr/index.html) package by Ozan Cinar and Wolfgang Viechtbauer. It includes functions for both Fisher and Stouffer methods.

Comment: Perhaps worth pointing out that it allows for non-independent p-values.